# How to compute torsion subgroup $E[24]$ over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, computational-number-theory

If I have an elliptic curve $E: y^2=x^3-15x+22$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ with CM from the imaginary quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ then how do I compute the $24$-torsion subgroup $E[24]$ over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$?

I know how to compute the $2,3$ and $4$-torsion subgroups using the following algorithm: if $P=(x,y)$ is a point on $E$ then if $2P=\mathcal{O}$ we have $y=0$. And, if $3P=\mathcal{O}$ then $x(2P)=x$ further if instead $4P=\mathcal{O}$ then $y(2P)=0$.

So, what should I do next? Compute $6$-torsion points by setting $y(3P)=0$? And, then in a similar way the $12$ and $24$-
torsion points? Or, is there any such similar algorithm?

Moreover, does there exist any program in SAGE or Magma that allows us to compute the torsion points over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$?

Comment: You start by adjoining the roots of the $n$-division polynomial. sage has .division_field(p) for prime numbers $p$ and the 4-torsion is not much harder if you copy the implementation of that function.  -- However the real question is: Do you want to calculate it? Normally you want its properties without having to create a field of such a large degree. I doubt you will be able to do much with it.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich well, what I ultimately want to do is to find the $24$-division field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})(E[24])$ so that I can find the galois group of this field extension over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$.  Do you have any comments on that?